# Rules Flag Count

Tags: 8, flags

I have added a flag [FOLLOW] that allows users to follow each other. Using Display Suite, I am trying to add a token field that will count total number a FOLLOWS a user has received.

From what I can gather you should be able to add token [flag-follow-count] but it is not working.

What is the right way to add a count to show how many times a user has been followed?

Comment: can you specify your drupal version? thanks

Comment: I am using Drupal 8.4

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it with Tokens but there is **Flag Followers** Views you can use.

The Page display already lists all users and their Follower count. You could add a Block display and set a contextual filter to filter out only one relevant user, depending on where exactly you want to display that Block.

If you do decide to edit the views it's good practice to Duplicate it and work on that instance, disable the original so you always have it intact for future reference.